# Убрать кавычки из переменной в Зowershell

Tags: powershell

Помогите разобраться с кавычками:)
Код:

```
  $file = Read-Host "Укажите путь к файлу"
  Get-FileHash -Path $file -Algorithm MD5
```

Вставляю путь к файлу вместе с кавычками.

```
"D:\myfile.zip"
```

И конечно получаю ошибку:

```
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"D' does not exist.
```

Потому что там кавычки.
Пытался разобраться с -replace, но так и не разобрался как его тут применить.

Comment: ¿Зачем вставлять путь вместо с кавычками? Это же не аргумент командной строки.

Comment: @user7860670 Кликаю правой кнопкой мыши по файлу и жму из выпадающего меню "Копировать как путь" таким образом путь копируется уже с кавычками, которые мне и надоело убирать:)

Answer (score 1):

Пока получилось решить проблему так:

```
$file = $file -replace '"',''
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку в переменной у тебя тип данных String(строка) то ты к нему можешь применять методы которые доступны для строк в данном случае метод .TRIM()

```
   $file = read-host "Укажите путь к файлу"
   Get-FileHash -Path ($file.Trim('"')) -Algorithm MD5
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. 
Переделал, как у тебя)